# When i opened Google page then every time an error was occur.Unable to create new remote session

Tags: selenium

When i trying to execute then every time an error message was occur.

```
Unable to create new remote session.desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@1660f4e, browserName=firefox,moz:firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@1660f4e, version=, platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
```

Code trials:

```
package com.rsmpl.hometask;


import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

 public class ComboValue {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\Arijit_Backup\\Utility\\Java_setup\\geckodriver.exe");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
            FirefoxDriver fd = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

            fd.get("http://74.50.58.66/jkhealth_test");

            Thread.sleep(10000);


        }

    }
```

Comment: Update the question with Selenium and other binary version information.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an admin account on your workstation? This might cause the issue.

Try specifying a path to Firefox in your capabilities:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\Arijit_Backup\\Utility\\Java_setup\\geckodriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("firefox_binary","pathToYourFirefoxExecutable\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
        FirefoxDriver fd = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

        fd.get("http://74.50.58.66/jkhealth_test");

        Thread.sleep(10000);


    }
```